# Multiple versions of factory girl factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, factory

Might be a basic question, but I can't find an answer.  I have a profile model and a profile can have several tags taken from a pre made list.  I want to use factory girl to create different profiles that each have different tags.  Here is my current code:

```
factory :profile do
  sequence(:user_id)  { |n| Student.find(n).id }
  sequence(:title)  { |n| "title #{n}" }
  sequence(:category) { |n| "category #{n}"}
  rate 8
  zip_code 11024
  description "Lorem ipsum timeLorem ipsum timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum timeLoem ipsum time"
  state "ny"
  tag_list ["php", "python"]
end
```

I have ten tags, and I want Factory Girl to create several profiles, all consisting of different combinations of the tags.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tags to be randomly selected when you create the profile, do this

```
factory :profile do
  sequence(:user_id)  { |n| Student.find(n).id }
  sequence(:title)  { |n| "title #{n}" }
  sequence(:category) { |n| "category #{n}"}
  rate 8
  zip_code 11024
  description "Lorem ipsum timeLorem ipsum timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum timeLoem ipsum time"
  state "ny"
  tag_list ["php", "python", "a"..].sample(2)
end

FactoryGirl.create_list(:profile, 10) #this will create 10 profiles with random tags
```

If you want to have control over what tag gets added, use [traits](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits)

```
    factory :profile do
      sequence(:user_id)  { |n| Student.find(n).id }
      sequence(:title)  { |n| "title #{n}" }
      sequence(:category) { |n| "category #{n}"}
      rate 8
      zip_code 11024
      description "Lorem ipsum timeLorem ipsum timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum t timeLorem ipsum timeLoem ipsum time"
      state "ny"
      tag_list ["php", "python", "a"..].sample(2)

      trait :tag_1 do
        tag_list [..]
      end

      trait :tag_2 do
        tag_list [..]
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your first suggestion but that always just takes the first two tags.  It does not make random tags.